# What should I do search results page by elasticsearch use elasticquent

Tags: laravel, search, elasticsearch

This is My code,
search some products by elasticsearch use a packagist elasticquent:

```
$query = [
    "body" => [
        "query" => [
            "function_score" => [
                "query" => [
                    "multi_match" => [
                        "query" => $keyword,
                        "analyzer"=>"standard",
                        "type" => "best_fields",
                        "fields" => [
                            0 => "name^5",
                            1 => "content^1",
                        ],
                        "fuzziness" => "AUTO",
                        "prefix_length" => 2
                    ],
                ],
                "field_value_factor" => [
                    "field" => "popular",
                    "modifier" => "log1p",
                    "factor" => "0.1",
                ],
                "boost_mode" => "sum",
                "max_boost" => "1.5",
            ],
        ],
    ],
];

$products = Product::complexSearch($query)->paginate(3);

//paging
$products->setPath('');

dd($products);
```

the result in browser is:

```
ElasticquentPaginator {#795 ▼
  #total: 290
  #lastPage: 97
  #items: Collection {#790 ▼
    #items: array:10 [▼
      0 => Product {#801 ▶}
      1 => Product {#804 ▶}
      2 => Product {#807 ▶}
      3 => Product {#779 ▶}
      4 => Product {#789 ▶}
      5 => Product {#785 ▶}
      6 => Product {#791 ▶}
      7 => Product {#782 ▶}
      8 => Product {#798 ▶}
      9 => Product {#788 ▶}
    ]
  }
  #perPage: 3
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: ""
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
  +"hits": array:3 [▶]
}
```

the Result number only 10, but the total is 290,and the  `paginate(3)` ,3 is not work,what should i do ?
thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Elasticsearch search size defaults to 10 as you can see in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html.

You can ask for more results by setting the *size* parameter to the desired number. Note that from version 2.0 onwards, you cannot set the size to >= 10000. If you wish to retrieve all the results that match your query you will have to use the scroll API: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html.

Comment: I use the elasticsearch is 1.7.4,can you tell me why I give a parameter 3,The  elasticsearch still use the default parameter 10,and the number 290 come from where? Thank you!

Comment: @Inmput Actually, I just observed better what is happening. You are asking your paginator to have 3 hits in each page. The actual results are in the "hits" field at the bottom of your response. You can see that you are in page 1 and there are 97 pages ("lastPage": 97). 97 * 3 = 291, so all 290 results fit in those 97 pages. You just have to iterate through the pages.

Comment: but the result is error,the real result is only 10, what should I do can solve the problem?